# setting syntax folder from vimrc

Tags: vim

Is there a way to set my syntax directory in vim to be a different folder than $VIMRUNTIME/.vim/syntax? I am currently trying to use a different python syntax file from work but I cannot install it to the general directory and would instead like to install from my own user folder (in this case, it would be ~/.vim/syntax).

Answer (score 0):

The `~/.vim` directory should work by default, I think. Have you tried creating it and seeing if it picks up your syntax file?

Try putting your syntax file in `~/.vim/after/syntax/`. I should run that syntax file after any other ones that it finds. This will also work for other folders, like `~/.vim/after/ftplugin`.

**Note:** You may have to create the `after` folder if it doesn't exist.